# Check instruction sets tensorflow build is compiled with

Tags: python, tensorflow, build, cpu, instruction-set

I am looking for a way to confirm that a tensorflow wheel was compiled with the correct instructions.

I am trying to build tensorflow for a Intel Atom CPU. I know that bazel will detect and build with appropriate instructions automatically, but I don't want to run the build on the Atom CPU because it is very slow. So I am running bazel on a i7 CPU with custom instructions instead. After obtaining the wheel, I would like to confirm that the instructions were actually used.

I found some python api that allows me to check MKL and other stuff, but don't know how to check for cpu instructions like sse. Any help please?

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import test_util as test

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('MKL enabled: %s' % test.IsMklEnabled())
    print('Google cuda enabled: %s' % test.IsGoogleCudaEnabled())
    print('GPU available: %s' % test.is_gpu_available())

    # cpu instruction set?
```